# Autohotkey - retrieve data into listbox from Excel with exceptions

Tags: excel, listbox, autohotkey

I have a list of numbers in an Excel sheet. The only interesting thing for me is in column B.

I'm using the following code to retrieve data from that sheet:

```
xlDown :=   -4121

fileselectfile, path


oExcel := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application") ;create a handle to a new excel application
oExcel.Visible := True ; by default excel sheets are invisible use true to see excel
oWorkBook := oExcel.Workbooks.open(path)

End := oExcel.Range("B1").End(xlDown).row
;Range_B := oExcel.Range("B1:B" . End) <--- would be good, but stops at every empty lines
Range_B := oExcel.Range("B1:B100") <--- I'm using this as my list is never longer than 100 entries

for cell in Range_B

    CONList .= cell.text "|"

GuiControl,, CONListVar, %CONList%

return
```

There are 3 types of data in this column, and I'm only interested in one, so I'd like to filter out the rest. Data types:

1. 7 digit numbers - I need these
2. Date in this format: DD.M.YYYY - I don't need these
3. Random blank cells - I don't need these

Is there a way to modify the following code or to manipulate the 'CONList' variable to filter down to only keep the 7 digit number? I cannot modify the Excel sheet, so I need to work with the output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `RegExMatch(cell.text, "^\d{7}$")` ?

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly could I insert this code?

Comment: Inside your loop: `if( RegExMatch(cell.text, "^\d{7}$") ) CONList .= ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the cell with `RegExMatch()` in each loop iteration:

```
for cell in Range_B
{
    if( RegExMatch(cell.text, "^\d{7}$") ) {
        CONList .= cell.text "|"
    }
}
```